# What game is shown at 10:22 in the video titled 'The Gaming Crash is coming'?

Tags: game-identification

I've just watched a video by The Dishonoured Wolf, titled *"The Gaming Crash Is Coming"* (archive linked below). While I recognized the first two games (Force Unleashed (I think) and Overwatch), I'm at a loss for the one shown at timestamp 10:22. What is it?

As a bonus, around 15:30 another game I don't recognize is shown, what is that one?

https://web.archive.org/web/20170916112207/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFqJjX7xRAY

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That first game is [Night in the Woods](http://store.steampowered.com/app/481510/Night_in_the_Woods/).

The second game is [Ori and the Blind Forest](http://store.steampowered.com/app/261570/Ori_and_the_Blind_Forest/).